# Apply different filters after main MultiMatch query in Elastic Search NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So, this is my query:

```
_elasticClient.Search<SearchItem>(x =>
                x.Sort(sort).Size(itemsPerPage)
                .Query(q =>
                    q.MultiMatch(m => m
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        .Field(p => p.Field1)
                        .Field(p => p.Field2)
                        .Field(p => p.Field3)
                        .Field(p => p.Field4)
                        .Field(p => p.Field5)
                        .Field(p => p.Field6)                            
                    )
                    .Operator(Operator.And)
                    .Query(pattern)
                )));
```

I have to apply different filters. Range filters (for price), filter result set where field1 = "Audi" and field2 = "Sale Car". I tried to do something like that:

```
.Query(q =>
                    q.MultiMatch(m => m
                    .Fields(fs => fs
                        Field(p => p.Field1)
                            .Field(p => p.Field2)
                            .Field(p => p.Field3)
                            .Field(p => p.Field4)
                            .Field(p => p.Field5)
                            .Field(p => p.Field6)  
                    )
                    .Operator(Operator.And)
                    .Query(pattern)))
.Query(q=>q.Range(ra=>ra.Field(ff=>ff.SalePrice).GreaterThan(1000))));
```

But this is not working. I've all results from the index with price greater then 1000, but need only searched results. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Use a `bool` query to combine both the `multi_match` and the `range` query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/bool-queries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **[use a `bool` query to combine queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/bool-queries.html)** and NEST makes this slightly easier to work with by overloading operators to combine `QueryContainer`s (the root query type). Here's an example for NEST 2.x

```
void Main()
{
    var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var itemsPerPage = 20;
    var pattern = "match query";

    client.Search<SearchItem>(x => x
        .Sort(so => so
            .Descending("_score")
        )
        .Size(itemsPerPage)
        .Query(q => q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Fields(fs => fs
                    .Field(p => p.Field1)
                    .Field(p => p.Field2)
                    .Field(p => p.Field3)
                    .Field(p => p.Field4)
                    .Field(p => p.Field5)
                    .Field(p => p.Field6)
                )
                .Operator(Operator.And)
                .Query(pattern)
            ) && q
            .Range(ra => ra
                .Field(ff=>ff.SalePrice)
                .GreaterThan(1000)
            )
        )
    );
}

public class SearchItem
{
    public int SalePrice { get; set; }

    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    public string Field4 { get; set; }

    public string Field5 { get; set; }

    public string Field6 { get; set; }
}
```

which yields

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "match query",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "field1",
              "field2",
              "field3",
              "field4",
              "field5",
              "field6"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "salePrice": {
              "gt": 1000.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will find documents that are a match for the `multi_match` query *and* also have a `salePrice` greater than 1000. Since we don't need a score calculated for the range query (a document either has a `salePrice` greater than 1000 or it doesn't), the range query can run in a filter context. A slightly refined version

```
client.Search<SearchItem>(x => x
    .Sort(so => so
        .Descending("_score")
    )
    .Size(itemsPerPage)
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(m => m
            .Fields(fs => fs
                .Field(p => p.Field1)
                .Field(p => p.Field2)
                .Field(p => p.Field3)
                .Field(p => p.Field4)
                .Field(p => p.Field5)
                .Field(p => p.Field6)
            )
            .Operator(Operator.And)
            .Query(pattern)
        ) && +q
        .Range(ra => ra
            .Field(ff=>ff.SalePrice)
            .GreaterThan(1000)
        )
    )
);
```

appending the unary `+` operator to the range query is a shorthand for a bool query filter. The query json now looks like

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "match query",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "field1",
              "field2",
              "field3",
              "field4",
              "field5",
              "field6"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "salePrice": {
              "gt": 1000.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```